# Debugging Call Stack Exceeded C# Backend

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a get route a that is going to get data of wells and well tests, when I execute the call on swagger, it will take awhile and then give me a call stack error. My problem is I cant figure out how to get a log or idea of where this is happening. The best I have been able to do so far is use point breaks at every step to see how far it gets. I've gotten to the controller route so I know that its grabbing the data just fine, my understanding is that it now has the data, and should use the view model to match and display the data. I have gone through about 100 data samples in the view model and it seems fine but there is 2400 units, all with 5 arrays inside of them. However it will simply error out with no message. Any ideas of whats going on or how to debug this? Is there a way in VS Code so see a better log of something like this or another tool that will do that will help in this situation?

[image]

** Service Code: **

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<SapDispatchViewModel>> GetDispatchDeliveryForSap()
    {
        var result = await _dispatchRepo.GetDispatchDeliveryForSap(TenantId);
        var view = new List<SapDispatchViewModel>();
        foreach (SapDispatch row in result)
        {
            var sapView = _mapper.Map<SapDispatch, SapDispatchViewModel>(row);         
            var items = await _dispatchItemRepo.GetDispatchItemsByTruckForSap(row.DispatchTruckId);
            var viewItems = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SapDispatchItem>, IEnumerable<SapDispatchItemViewModel>>(items);
            sapView.Items = viewItems;
            view.Add(sapView);
        }

        return view; 
    }
```

** It calls this GetDispatchDeliveryForSap first: **

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SapDispatch>> GetDispatchDeliveryForSap(string TenantId)
    {
        string deliveryType = "Delivery";
        
        //resort to raw SQL to assist with performance improvements
        FormattableString sql = $@"
        WITH cte_latestStatus AS
        ( SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT
                s.TenantId,
                s.DispatchId,
                s.DispatchHeaderId,
                s.RequestedArrival,
                s.EstimatedArrival,
                s.Status,
                u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName UserName,
                s.CreateDate StatusChangeDate,
                row_number() over(partition by DispatchHeaderId order by CreateDate desc) as rn
            FROM
                DispatchStatus s
                JOIN AspNetUsers u on s.CreateUserId = u.Id
        ) t
        WHERE t.rn = 1
        )

        select w.wellid,
            w.wellname, 
            wo.ErpId,
            wc.ContractorName + ' ' + w.RigNumber Rig,
            w.CountyParish County,
            w.State,
            d.type DispatchType, 
            u.LastName + ',' + u.FirstName OrderedBy, 
            ds.RequestedArrival RequestedDate,
            dt.DriverName, 
            dt.SwamperName,
            dt.TicketNumber,
            dt.DispatchTruckId
        from well w
        join Dispatch d on w.wellid = d.DestinationWellId
        join cte_latestStatus ds on d.DispatchId = ds.DispatchId and d.HeaderId = ds.DispatchHeaderId
        join DispatchTruck dt on d.DispatchId = dt.DispatchId
        join AspNetUsers u on d.CreateUserId = u.Id
        left join WellContractorRef wcr on w.WellId = wcr.WellId
        left join Contractor wc on wcr.ContractorId = wc.ContractorId
        left join WellOperatorRef wor on w.WellId = wor.WellId
        left join Operator wo on wor.OperatorId = wo.OperatorId
        --join DispatchItem di on dt.DispatchTruckId = di.DispatchTruckId
        where d.TenantId = {TenantId}
        and d.type = {deliveryType}
        and (ds.Status = 'Completed' or dt.status = 'Completed')
        order by w.wellname"
        ;
        var result = await context.SapDispatches.FromSqlInterpolated(sql).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        return result;
        
    }
}
```

}

** Then maps via the view model to create the list: **

```
namespace Mudman.Model.ViewModels
 {
  public class SapDispatchViewModel
{
    public string WellId { get; set; }
    public string WellName { get; set; }
    public string ErpId { get; set; }
    public string Rig { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string DispatchType { get; set; }
    public string OrderedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RequestedDate { get; set; }
    public string DriverName { get; set; }
    public string SwamperName { get; set; }
    public long? TicketNumber { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SapDispatchItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

}

public class SapDispatchItemViewModel
{
    public string ErpId { get; set; }
    public Decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public Decimal? Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
}
```

}

** From there, it runs the foreach on the GetDispatchItemsForTruckSap: **

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SapDispatchItem>> GetDispatchItemsByTruckForSap(string dispatchTruckId)
    {
        //resort to raw SQL to assist with performance improvements
        FormattableString sql = $@"
        WITH cte as (
            SELECT 
                COALESCE(ProductId, ExpenseId) AS SalesItemID,
                Price,
                Quantity
            FROM DispatchItem
            WHERE DispatchTruckId = {dispatchTruckId}
        )

        SELECT si.ErpId,
            cte.Price,
            cte.Quantity,
            si.Size,
            si.Unit
        FROM SalesItem si
        INNER JOIN cte on cte.SalesItemID = si.SalesItemId"
        ;
        var result = await context.SapDispatchItems.FromSqlInterpolated(sql).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        return result;

    }
}
```

}

** Maps with the Item View Model: **

```
    public class SapDispatchItemViewModel
{
    public string ErpId { get; set; }
    public Decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public Decimal? Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
}
```

}

** Then it will hit the return and thats where it will error out.

Also, here is what the callstack is looking like when you hit that return.

[image]

Comment: First and foremost, ALWAYS post code as Text. Images can be added, but text is *required*. Second, the error happens in the `Ok()` method which might mean that the error is happening as a result of converting the `result` object into JSON text output. What is the **Type** of `result`? And what is its content, e.g. can you show `result` in a Debugger view? This IDE looks like VS Code, have you tried running it in the free(!) [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/), which has a better debugger for .NET?

Comment: Would need to see what this `GetDispatchDeliveryForSap()` method returns and what it is doing. (Should use the `Async` suffix for asynchronous methods)  If the "Ok" method is where it's failing then the issue will most likely be with your API trying to serialize the resulting data. It isn't clear whether you are trying to return entities or DTOs, as the other code seems to mention an "internal" view model vs. model being passing in.

Comment: @PeterB great point, I should have included the code, thank you for keeping me honest. It is updated and I'll try to see if I can get result into the debugger for a better view.

Comment: @StevePy updated with the code. Those are great questions, I can't say I fully understand them so that seems to be the first thing today I need to go back and try to understand.

Comment: Ok, nothing too suspicious there, the important thing is it's returning view models, no entity references. It looks like you get to the point of returning the Ok result (ObjectResult) and can breakpoint on that when testing it with Swagger, but then Swagger is resulting in an error? If other similar methods (HttpGet returning Ok(object)) are working via swagger then you may be hitting a response length limit. As a test, try `var result = await _dispatchRepo.GetDispatchDeliveryForSap(TenantId).Take(2);` to force a smaller result set. If it works, get a count and test for a rough size limit.

Comment: If there is a limit getting in the way it should be possible to configure the server to increase that limit but you might need to consider setting an expectation on limiting and/or paginating results.

Comment: On a side note, the use of custom SQL for performance looks to be re-inventing what Automapper's `ProjectTo` method could provide, and that most likely could do away with the Select N+1 inner loop. I don't think that will be related to the issue you're seeing though.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on Break When Thrown on Common Language Runtime Exceptions and it should break at the error:

[image]